# Master list scroll not enable to scroll

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to create a master/detail page with a master list that I don't know will do not scroll. I tried use enablescrolling property, use a scroll container and nothing.

Here is my xmlview:

```xml
<masterPages>
                            <Page showHeader="false" title="Master Page Title" enableScrolling="true">
                                <ScrollContainer vertical="true">
                                    <SelectList itemPress="onListItemPress">
                                        <items>
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 1" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 2" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 3" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 1" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 2" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 3" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 1" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 2" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 3" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 1" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 2" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 3" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 1" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 2" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 3" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 1" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 2" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 3" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 1" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 2" type="Active" />
                                            <core:Item text="To Detail 3" type="Active" />
                                        </items>
                                    </SelectList>
                                </ScrollContainer>
                            </Page>
                        </masterPages>
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the sap.m.List control in your master page. For this control, you don't have to implement ScrollContainer, scrolling is provided by the List automatically (called growing).

[Here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.List/samples) are some great samples in this topic.

And a small example:

```
<List>
  <items>
     <ObjectListItem title="To Detail 1"/>
     <ObjectListItem title="To Detail 2"/>
  </items>
```

You can use different kind of List Items, it depends on your requirements. For more information, check [this](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html) link. All the list items can be found in the header's 'known direct subclasses' section.